How to convert 00d 00h 07m 42s into a time value
I have imported a large amount of data but the format of the time data is hard to work with and must be converted into a time value.
The current data is stored as a nvarchar and cannot be converted to int or time. I tried to use :
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE ([ERGTalk time],'00d ',''),'h ',':'),'m ',':'),'s','') AS [ERGTalk Time Conversion],

as a method to strip all characters but it still can't be converted or cast.
An example is the time value originally is 00d 00h 02m 07s and the desired result is 00:00:02:07

Please show sample data and desired results within your question.

It's not a time value, it's a duration. As in, durations can span multiple days.

The SQL Server time data type represents a time of day. It appears that what you're trying to import is some representation of a time span. Realise that those are not the same types, so you should probably be aiming for an int in the smallest units you're interested in, e.g. seconds.

First, as others said, that's not a time and SQL Server doesn't have an interval type. Second, conversions should happen before saving the data. SQL is a query language and SQL Server is weaker than other databases in text manipulation. It's a lot easier to parse this in C# or Python.

The REPLACE does work and can be cast as long as the interval is less than 1 day. cast(REPLACE ...... as time) works. The resulting time would be useless though. time values can't be summed or averaged the way intervals can.

Is the string always of the format 00d 00h 00m 00s? i.e. there are always exactly two digits reserved for days, hours, minutes and seconds? if so you can easily use CHARINDEX to extract the values from the known offsets and no need to use string_split

As others has mention in the comments, you can't really convert that string to a  time. it does not make sense.
You can however convert it to an integer value that represent the interval period. To do that you can't simply convert it. You need to parse each individual element of the string. Assuming that your string is well structured and always have space to separate the element, you can use string_split() to split it and then do some simple parsing and sum() up the value.
select s.talk_time, [interval in seconds] = sum(i.i)
from   #sample s
       cross apply string_split(s.talk_time, ' ') v
       cross apply
       (
           select i = left(v.value, len(v.value) - 1)
                    * case right(v.value, 1)
                      when 'd' then 24 * 60 * 60
                      when 'h' then 60 * 60
                      when 'm' then 60
                      when 's' then 1
                      end
       ) i
group by s.talk_time

db<>fiddle demo
